# Android - how do I get the release key for my application?

Tags: android, apk

I saved my project.apk file, and I was reading this document: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#setup and they kind of skip over the details of how to actually obtain a release key.

Is there a site that just generates this key for me? Does Goolge app store have to know about the key too? I am confused :)

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll down to "Signing in Release Mode"

You can create a self-singed certificate, or use a signing authority. I expect most people use a self-signed cert.

DO NOT LOSE that cert or you will not be able to make updates to your app.

And the easies way for signing is using Eclipse and ADT. 
You just right click on your project folder and select:

Android Tools>Export Signed Application Package

Comment: Thanks I never made a self-signed certificate before :) How does it look like and how do I make one? lol

Comment: Rock on @GeekedOut. Welcome to the world of published android app developers :-)